# almacene 10 numeros por teclado en un array y que luego muestre el máximo valor, el mínimo y las posiciones que ocupan en el array

Tags: java, array

Este es mi codigo y al final solo me imprime el valor maximo y la posicion del numero mayor, pero no  me imprime el valor minimo y la posicion del menor valor.(imprime cero)

```
        int[]numeros = new int[10];
        int max=0, min=0, posmax=0, posmin=0;
        System.out.println("Introduzca 10 numeros\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
            numeros[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
            if(numeros[i]>max){
                max=numeros[i];
                posmax=i;
            }
            if(numeros[i]<min){
                min=numeros[i];
                posmin=i;
            }
        
        System.`out.printf("Valor Máximo =  %d y la posicion del numero es: %d ", max, posmax);
        System.out.printf("Valor Mínimo =  %d y la posicion del numero es: %d ", min, posmin);
```

Comment: El problema es que estás inicializando los valores máximo y mínimo en cero. Mejor los inicializas ambos como el primer elemento de tu Array, luego recorres el Array a partir del segundo elemento y actualizas tal como lo haces actualmente. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: el problema esta en el if(numeros[i]<min) ya que siempre pregunta si el numero es menor que 0 y parece que esta condición no se cumple, por ello termina siendo 0

lo mismo pasaría con el if(numeros[i]>max) si el array solo tuviera números negativos.

tal y como dijo @MauricioContreras lo mejor seria inicializar las variables con el primer elemento del array y en los if preguntar si son >= y <=

Comment: @JoséVenegas el problema con usar >= y <= es que estarías actualizando el índice, por lo tanto estarías devolviendo el índice del último elemento con valor mínimo y el índice del último elemento con valor máximo. Considera el siguiente array: [2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 7]. Si quiero los valores mínimo y máximo y sus índices, deseo los primeros (en orden ascendente de índice) que cumplan con dicha condición, en este caso el mínimo está en la posición 0 y vale 2, y el máximo está en la posición 5 y vale 7. Saludos